# SSLHandShakeException occurring on the first request to the server

Tags: sslhandshakeexception, device-owner, ssl-handshake, android-device-owner

I am encountering an SSLHandshakeException when making the first request in my device owner app. The app is automatically installed after reboot by scanning a QR code that contains the download location and server details. The server has a trusted third-party certificate and the device has the root of the server certificate.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

However, I found that the issue is resolved if I introduce a delay(400 ms) before making the first request.